# debug not working for rest method PUT using postman rest client

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, debugging, postman

I have two Uri's

POST : http://localhost:8080/applications/2851/involved-parties/1/contacts
PUT : http://localhost:8080/applications/2851/involved-parties/1/contacts

I am trying to debug methods,I have added breakpoint for both methods at starting,
   started server in debug mode. while sending json request using
   postman rest client for POST method cursor stop you at break point at
   POST method. but same request for PUT method does not work your
   cursor does not stop you at break point its directly giving response
   back to client.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/applications/{applicationReferenceNumber}/involved-parties/{id}/contacts", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public PutApplicationsResponse putContacts(@Valid @RequestBody final PutApplicationsRequest req,
        final BindingResult bind, @PathVariable(value = "applicationReferenceNumber") final Long arn,
        @PathVariable(value = "id") final Integer id, @RequestHeader final HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
        final HttpServletRequest reqHTTP) throws ContactsException, SQLException, MethodArgumentNotValidException,
                HttpMessageNotReadableException {

    reqHTTP.setAttribute(ExceptionConstants.ARN, arn);
    reqHTTP.setAttribute(ExceptionConstants.id, id);
    objMp = new ObjectMapper();

    if (bind.hasErrors()) {
        throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(null, bind);
    }
```

FYI : I am testing negative scenario for both method e.g. length for id is 4 if I pass the 5 length for id then it has to return exception

Regards,

Comment: yes, I am selecting the method in postman

Comment: pls show the server side code for `PUT` method

Answer (score 0):

Normally with a PUT request to update, the particular resource URI should be known. So say the client makes a request to:

`http://blah.com/applications/{applicationReferenceNumber}/involved-parties/{id}/contacts`

Our service will look up the the id passsed. If it can't be found, we return a 404 status code, as the resource doesn't exist. If it does exist, then we update the contacts for the application id provided in the request. If you wanted to create a contacts, where the URI is not known, then POST would be correct, and you'd send a application id representation to:

`http://blah.com/applications/{applicationReferenceNumber}/involved-parties/{id}/contacts`

So basically if resource is available and we are doing put operation it will update directly on the server and also it is idempotent so evrytime you fire PUT request it will not do any other changes where as POST will create new resource every time and hence it will go through the code all the time.

Comment: that's correct resource is available and I want it to update via PUT method but the question is why I can't debug the PUT method like POST

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, you'll probably need to send the data via POST and then add the _method field as part of the request.

```
_method:put
```